# Laravel - performance of Facades vs. helper methods

Tags: php, performance, laravel-5, laravel-facade

I wonder if there is a performance difference between using Facades and helper methods in laravel 5.1.

I startet to remove for example `use View;` or `View::make()` wherever possible, thinking that `view()` would be simpler and possibly faster. But I don't know.

Same with `Redirect::to()` --> `redirect()` , `Redirect::back()` --> `back()` and so on..

Is there a difference or does it not matter?

Comment: On another note, if there's nothing regarding performance, is there any other reason to use Facades vs. helper functions?

Comment: I do not think there would be any performance boost. Those are static functions, so it won't make real difference.

Comment: It's mainly stylistic, Facades basically provide a static interface to the underlying classes in the Laravels IoC container, meaning that you don't need to manually do dependency injection yourself.   I prefer to use the helper functions as I don't like cluttering my code with static interface calls where I don't need too, however this will vary from developer to developer!

Comment: @MinaAbadir why there should not be a performance boost? A facade is static call to `Facade::__callStatic()` -> `static::getFacadeRoot()` -> `static::resolveFacadeInstance(static::getFacadeAccessor())` -> `app()->make()->$method` while the helper directly calls `app()->make()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is much performance difference but one thing to consider is the reduced cognitive load of always including the `use` statement when using a facade. Just one more thing to forget.