# Auth::check() vs auth()->check()

Tags: laravel, authentication

I've noticed there are different "formats" to probably express/enable the same.

What is the (practical) difference between Auth::check() and auth()->check()?

Comment: Facade vs global helper function. I don't believe there is any practical difference, just preference.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324226/laravel-performance-of-facades-vs-helper-methods

Comment: The only _real_ difference is that the `auth()` helper allow you to pass a `guard` parameter directly. `auth('someGuard')->check()` does the same things as  `Auth::guard('someGuard')->check()`, but it saves a function call. Other than that, they are exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

`auth()` is a global helper that is available everywhere in Laravel.

`Auth` is a Facade that is traditionally made available via Imports (a `use` statement at the top of a PHP file):

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

public class ExampleController {
  public function index() {
    dd(Auth::check());
  }
}
```

If you omitted that `use` statement, `Auth::check()` would trigger an error (unknown/unresolvable Class `Auth`).

`Auth` is also made available in `.blade.php` views by being included in Laravel's `config\app.php` file:

```php
'aliases' => Facade::defaultAliases()->merge([
  /* App-specific aliases (if any) are listed here */
])->toArray()
```

`Facade::defaultAliases()` points to:

```php
public static function defaultAliases() {
  return collect([
    'Auth' => Auth::class,
    /* Additional default aliases are listed here */
  ]);
}
```

If you removed `Facade::defaultAliases()->merge([])`, `Auth` would no longer function in `.blade.php` files. In previous versions of Laravel, these Aliases were hard-coded into `config/app.php`, which made it easier to pick and choose which Aliases to load and which Aliases to omit, but the current approach is a little cleaner.

To answer the actual question, the main difference is preference.

Personally, I typically go with `auth()->method()` vs `Auth::method()` (or any other `helper()->method()` instead of `Helper::method()`) simply due to readability and global availability, but performance-wise, there's no (or negligible) difference, so use whichever you or your team prefers.